# Purpose of bitwise operation in this example

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, osdev

In the function `outb(0x3D5, (uint8_t) (pos & 0xFF));`, I am having trouble understanding the purpose of the bitwise operation. *pos* is a `uint16_t` variable.

What is the purpose of the bitwise `&` with simply 8 bits of 1. The `&` operation would just compare this value with 8 bits of 1, which to my knowledge, would just result in the same value. How does this operation change the value of *pos*?

For background if it is important, the function `outb` is intended to move the value of the right argument into the register indexed by the port (left argument). In this case, *pos* is a position in VGA adapter memory. The function `outb` uses inline assembly and the assembly instruction `out`.

Comment: It's probably just some coding habit of the one who wrote that code.

Answer (score 5):

> The `&` operation would just compare this value with 8 bits of 1s, which to my knowledge, would just result in the same value.

The `&` operation does not “compare” values. It performs a bitwise AND. When the 16-bit `pos` is ANDed with `0xFF`, the result is the low eight bits of `pos`. Thus, if `pos` is `0x1234u`, then `pos & 0xFF` will produce the value of `0x34u`.

The conversion to `uint8_t` with the cast `(uint8_t)` would produce the same value, because a conversion of an integer to `uint8_t` wraps the value modulo 2<sup>8</sup>, which, for non-negative integers, is equivalent to taking the low eight bits.

Thus, these expressions all produce the same value:

- `pos & 0xFF`,
- `(uint8_t) pos`, and
- `(uint8_t) (pos & 0xFF)`.

(For negative integers, wrapping modulo 2<sup>8</sup> and taking the low eight bits are not equivalent if the C implementation uses sign-and-magnitude or one’s complement representations, which are allowed by the C standard but are very rare these days. Of course, no `uint16_t` values are negative.)

Comment: Since outb should be defined as `void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t value)` all 3 expressions would also be equivalent to just `pos`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Without official documentation for OP’s target platform, I would not assume `outb`’s second parameter is not declared `char`, which could be signed, in which case the conversion would be implementation-defined for values outside the range of `char`.

Comment: If outb takes a signed char then `(uint8_t) pos` would be implementation-defined for values outside the range of `char` too. I assumed the value is `uint8_t` because that's what the cast uses too. Also I've never seen outb defined as taking a signed integer.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Conversions to `uint_8` are fully defined by the C standard; the result for any input value is identical in every conforming C implementation. Conversions to signed `char` are not fully defined by the C standard; the results may vary in different conforming C implementations.

Comment: I was referring to the conversion from uint8_t to signed char on the outb call.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: The platform is x86, as we can see from the tags.  All real-world x86 C implementations can round-trip a `uint8_t` to `char` and back without munging it, with the cast preserving the bit-pattern.  I believe GNU C even specifically defines the behaviour.  (And yes, x86 C implementations (ABIs) by convention have `char` as a signed type, unlike ARM for example where `char` is unsigned.)  But fair point in the general case of masking and casting, or Deathstation 9000 x86 C implementations.